# Xamarin.Forms: BLE + background service

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms, mobile

Есть медицинское устройство, которое подключается по bluetooth LE к приложению на смартфоне (Xamarin.Forms - Android, iOS). Необходимо поддерживать постоянное соединение с устройством 24/7. Сейчас использую Plugin.BLE и ForegroundService. Однако соединение с устройством всё равно рвется через некоторое время (от нескольких минут до часов).

Каков правильный путь решения данной задачи?
Постоянное соединение с устройством критично.

Comment: Нашел несколько статей - грешат на spotify https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43160195/android-ble-unexpectedly-and-repeatedly-reconnects-to-peripheral/43688791#43688791 так же нашел может быть вам поможет - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32886131/how-to-scan-the-ble-device-in-background-service-without-library

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato, спасибо за интерес. Но, кажется, Spotify исправили эту проблему. Кроме того, на целевом устройстве не установлен Spotify.

Comment: Я скажу за Андроид. Исходя из практики ForegroundService система удаляет через несколько часов или суток. Можно попробовать в активности установить "не выключать экран" и оставлять устройство подключенным к питанию. В сервисе постоянно проверять соединение по bluetooth.. Могу перенести в ответ если устроит Удачи..

Answer (score 1):

### [flutter_foreground_task](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_foreground_task)

- Может выполнять повторяющиеся задачи со службой переднего плана.
- Предоставляет полезные утилиты (minimizeApp, wakeUpScreen и т.д.), которые можно использовать при выполнении задачи.
- Предоставляет виджет, который предотвращает закрытие приложения во время работы службы переднего плана.
- Предоставляет виджет для запуска службы переднего плана, когда приложение свернуто или закрыто.
- Предоставляет возможность автоматического возобновления службы переднего плана при загрузке.

> Этот плагин для задач `переднего плана`. Для Android вы можете
> использовать опцию `Ignoe_Battery_optimisation`, и приложение будет
> продолжать работать в фоновом режиме, пока вы не проведете пальцем
> вверх по приложению, и если вы хотите, чтобы `ble Connection`
> отключился от устройства в приложении `swipUp` из памяти, вам нужно
> добавить несколько дополнительных шагов, и он также работает для
> `IOS`, просто добавьте `UiBackgroundModes` для `Bluetooth` и всего
> остального, и приложение будет продолжать работать в фоновом режиме,
> если вы постоянно что-то делаете с Bluetooth
> [@rohitsangwan01](https://bytemeta.vip/repo/PhilipsHue/flutter_reactive_ble/issues/500)

Если я правильно понял - плагин дает возможность перевести ЛЮБОЕ приложение на передний план и заставить его работать пока его не смахнут, или не выключат иначе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вряд ли это можно считать решением задачи, но за не имением других ответов решил поделиться, мне кажется это может сработать.